Get the virtual address of a specific instruction in Linux Kernel
I recently worked on a job that required me to get the address of a particular instruction in a code segment of Linux Kernel, , I tried to do this with the Labels as Values provided by gcc. like this:
u64 address;

noinline void foo()
{
    address = (u64)&&label;
    // some code

label: // the virtual address I want
    // some code
}

But the value of address is not correct, it's given as &foo. I guess the reason for the error is that address is not a static constant(It's a global value), and this is an assignment procedure, not an initialization procedure.
I would like to know if there is a way to "get the virtual address of any instruction and store it in a variable" in the linux kernel.

Maybe my abstract example wasn't good, so I put up the full version of the situation:
I wrote a function in the linux kernel that looks like this:
u64 sgt[16][3];

void my_foo(void)
{
    sgt[2][0] = (u64) &&begin;
    sgt[2][1] = (u64) &&end;
begin:
    __asm__ volatile(".byte 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x55 \n\t");
end:
    return;
}

I want sgt[2][0] and sgt[2][1] to record the values of && begin and && end respectively.
That is, it should be he virtual addresses of __asm__ volatile(".byte 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x55 \n\t"); and return; statements.
But my disassembly didn't turn out as expected.
void my_foo(void)
{
ffffffc008026d40:   d503245f    bti c
    sgt[2][0] = (u64) &&begin;
ffffffc008026d44:   d00062e0    adrp    x0, ffffffc008c84000 <cpu_release_addr+0x688>
ffffffc008026d48:   91070000    add x0, x0, #0x1c0
{
ffffffc008026d4c:   d503233f    paciasp
    sgt[2][0] = (u64) &&begin;
ffffffc008026d50:   90000002    adrp    x2, ffffffc008026000 <arch_prctl_spec_ctrl_set+0x270>
    sgt[2][1] = (u64) &&end;
ffffffc008026d54:   90000001    adrp    x1, ffffffc008026000 <arch_prctl_spec_ctrl_set+0x270>
    sgt[2][0] = (u64) &&begin;
ffffffc008026d58:   91351042    add x2, x2, #0xd44
    sgt[2][1] = (u64) &&end;
ffffffc008026d5c:   9135c021    add x1, x1, #0xd70
ffffffc008026d60:   a9030402    stp x2, x1, [x0, #48]
begin:
    __asm__ volatile(".byte 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x55 \n\t");
ffffffc008026d64:   55000002    .word   0x55000002
end:
    return;
}
ffffffc008026d68:   d50323bf    autiasp
ffffffc008026d6c:   d65f03c0    ret

I would like x1 and x2 to be 0xffffffc008026d64 and ffffffc008026d68 respectively, but they are 0xffffffc008026d44 and 0xffffffc008026d70.

Your language is not sufficiently clear. When you say “instruction” do you mean C code statement or are you talking about machine code? You ask about kernel code, but then provide your own code, which by definition is not kernel code (unless you are planning to somehow sneak it in to linux distributions?). —— Anything in the kernel is protected memory anyway. You shouldn’t be able to access it beyond invoking a function.

Are you compiling this code with optimization?

I apologize for my lack of clarity, when I say instruction I mean statement in C. That level of granularity is enough for me. This really isn't native kernel code, it's a simplified example of my modifications to the kernel code. The reason I emphasize that it is kernel code is that I thought it was a piece of code in EL1 that used aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc and followed the kernel build process. I'm worried that I've overlooked some configuration items in the build.

Why would address need to be a constant? Most of the examples in the documentation don't use constants. One of the points of using label pointers is that you can assign them dynamically to implement a computed goto.

I noticed in the documentation that &&label is a constant, so I also assumed that my assigning a constant to a variable (or assigning a local label to a global variable) would be the cause of the problem. I'm not really sure why it's not working properly, it's just a guess on my part.

It's also possible that the Kernel is building with some optimization of gcc that is causing the problem, but I don't know how to troubleshoot it.
